# Pass object containing two integers or different method?

Tags: java, android, cocos2d-iphone

I have this method. It takes a Node and I need it to take two ints.

```
   public void resetAnchorpoints(Object sender, Object passed){
        Log.v("TAG", "CALLED FUNCTION 1!" + sender.toString());
        Log.v("TAG", "The center tile was " + (int[]) passed[1] + "," + (int[]) passed[2]);
    }
```

To call it, I use `CCCallFuncND mresetAnchorpoint = CCCallFuncND.action(this, "resetAnchorpoints", pass);`

As I gather, CCCallFuncND passes one Node (N) and a Data Object (D). However, if i compose the data object like this :

`int[] pass = new int[3];
                    pass[0] = cC;
                    pass[1] = cR;`

It doesn't work (because it needs to be an Object?). So my question is : How do I 'pack' two int-s in one object, and use them in my resetAnchorpoints method?

//Edit ; forgot to mention error. The error is :"02-27 18:54:22.898    4925-4961/nl.happyworx.squareone W/System.err﹕ java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: resetAnchorpoints [class java.lang.Object, class java.lang.Object]"

Thanks.

Comment: What is the error?  You should be able to pass an `int[]` array as an `Object`.  Maybe try to declare a new variable at the top of your method like so: `int[] params = (int[])passed;`  and then access your integers by `params[0]` and `params[1]`.

Comment: @dubstylee yeah you are correct, I retested what I had and int[] actually did work.

Comment: may be calling wrong action() not sure about the signature but one thing is sure as mentioned by @dub stylee you can of course pass int array if parameter types is Object as arrays are object type.

Comment: Also, be sure to access the correct index.  Indices are 0-based in most languages, so your first item would be `params[0]`.  Looks like you were assigning them correctly, but then accessing them with `1` and `2` in your method.

Comment: Sorry forgot to mention error : 02-27 18:54:22.898    4925-4961/nl.happyworx.squareone W/System.err﹕ java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: resetAnchorpoints [class java.lang.Object, class java.lang.Object]


Solutions suggested below do not solve the problem :(

Answer (score 0):

Use an `ArrayList`:

```
List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>();
list.add(cc);
list.add(cR);
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with the cast, see this example:

```
Object intArray = new int[] { 1 };
System.out.println((int[])intArray[0]); //fails
System.out.println(((int[])intArray)[0]); //works
```

So change your code to:

```
Log.v("TAG", "The center tile was " + ((int[]) passed)[0] + "," + ((int[]) passed)[1]);
```

As pointed out in the comments, you can also just cast it at the start:

```
passed = (int[])passed;
Log.v("TAG", "The center tile was " + passed[0] + "," + passed[1]);
```